# Is there a way to programmatically set the default directory with File System Access API

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem, native-file-system-api-js, file-system-access-api

Is there a way to set a defined directory path programmatically instead of showing the file explorer with .showDirectoryPicker() for the user to select the actual path?

Comment: Like this? https://web.dev/file-system-access/#specifying-a-suggested-file-name-and-start-directory

Comment: Not really, what i'm trying to achieve is to basically set the FileSystemDirectoryHandle programmatically so not showing the file explorer at all but would still be asking permission...

Comment: Like this?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle/getDirectoryHandle

Comment: Nope, that would be just for getting the subdirectories. I would still need the 'root' directory which is what I want to set programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain a handle to your desired root directory once via [`showDirectoryPicker()`](https://web.dev/file-system-access/#opening-a-directory-and-enumerating-its-contents). You can from thereon [store the handle to the directory in IndexedDB](https://web.dev/file-system-access/#storing-file-handles-or-directory-handles-in-indexeddb) and continue from there, even after a reload. Note, though, that you need to [check permissions](https://web.dev/file-system-access/#stored-file-or-directory-handles-and-permissions) each time, since once granted permissions are not restored, but must be re-obtained each time, at least for the moment.

Comment: This unfortunately isn't possible in an extension (bugs [#1368818](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1368818)/etc). I don't suppose you know of any other options?

Comment: The main bug to track is [crbug/1359786](https://crbug.com/1359786) (your linked one was merged into that one). Until this is resolved, unfortunately there's no other way around it.